# How do I convert from BLOB SUB_TYPE 0 to TEXT in Firebird?

Tags: php, blob, firebird

I have a field in my Firebird database table with data type as BLOB SUB_TYPE 0 (default). How can I view the content as text/string using a SELECT query in a PHP webservice SQL query?

I'm trying this:

```
<?php 
  
$str_conn="firebird:host=localhost;dbname=C:\Temporal\POLICLINICA.GDB;charset=utf8";
     
$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, "SYSDBA", "masterkey");

$res=$dbh->query("SELECT COD_PACIENTE, CONVERT(TRATAMIENTO USING utf8) AS TREAT, SESIONES FROM GES_FISOTERAPIA");

$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $datos[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($datos);

?>
```

The column 'Tratamiento' containing the blob type, but return error.

I must read the column in the webservice because I am not authorized to change the format in the database to TEXT or VARCHAR.

Comment: What do you mean with _"but return error"_? If you get an error, then please include that error in your question. Note that `CONVERT(TRATAMIENTO USING utf8)` is not valid in Firebird. There is nu function called `CONVERT` defined.

Comment: With a BLOB field you get out exactly what you put in, so just SELECT it like anything else. If you put text into it you'll get text out of it.

Comment: @Sammitch Blob handling can sometimes be a bit unwieldy (I don't know if PDO abstracts that away or not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `blob sub_type 0` is a `blob sub_type binary`, and contains binary data. If you are sure it is actually character data, and if the character set used is UTF8, then you can explicitly cast it:

```
cast(TRATAMIENTO as blob sub_type text character set utf8)
```

If instead you need `varchar`, you need to do either

```
cast(cast(binval as blob sub_type text character set utf8) as varchar(8191))
```

or

```
cast(cast(binval as varchar(8191) character set binary) as varchar(8191) character set utf8)
```

This seems convoluted, but I needed to do this, because it looks direct conversion from binary blob to varchar with character set doesn't work (at least, I got invalid results in Firebird 3 for non-ASCII characters).

I think that is a bug, and use of `cast(binval as varchar(8191) character set utf8)` should work (but right now it doesn't).

Be aware that when converting to varchar this way, the maximum length of the value is limited: 32765 for single byte character sets, and 8191 for (max) 4 byte character sets like utf8.

You may need to actually use the blob, and explicitly read the blobs.

Comment: Thanks, Mark Rotteveel! That's solved my problem! I tried some solutions of the proposals, and in the end it worked this one: `cast(TRATAMIENTO as varchar(8191) character set utf8)`. :D